# Create instance of object when type is stored in a variable without using eval

Tags: javascript

I've a bunch of objects written in javascript that represent, advanced reusable controls. These controls are placed in a page somewhere as div with a type attribute. Selecting these is easy but creating the appropiate javascript object and passing the selected node to the appropiate types init function is less straight forward. I'm trying to avoid building a string along the lines of 'new ' + controlType + '(' + selector + ')' and then calling eval on it.

Answer (score 3):

If the each constructor function is global, you can access them explicitly via the `window` object (the global object):

```
var instance = new window[controlType](selector):
```

Otherwise I recommend to create a "namespace" for the constructor functions

```
var types = {
    'TypeA': TypeA,
    'TypeB': TypeB,
    //...
};
```

and do the same as above.